# Are there GURPS Illuminati side books?

Tags: religions-and-deities, gurps

Wondering here if there aren't similar books that could be used together with GURPS Illuminati, similar, a common cross-over between GURPS Magic and GURPS Fantasy, maybe with elements of GURPS Conan.

Aren't there more books that would fit in GURPS Illuminati world?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*You seem to be looking for Conspiracy books. Would you like some help?*

## [Madness Dossier](http://www.sjgames.com/gurps/books/madnessdossier/)

Sumerian gods used to be the slavers of humanity, but that happened in a parallel history a long time ago. Now, that history was/is undone, but not permanently, at least not necessarily. Today, the remnants of that history occasionally emerge, trying to set wrong that once somehow turned right. And our secret organisations are waging a war in the shadows to prevent that.

There's spooky mind-magic, monsters that seem to be influenced by both Robert E. Howard and Howard Phillips Lovecraft, and eerie tech. Also psychological horror. I think this is the closest match to what you seem to be describing.

## [Conspiracy X](http://www.sjgames.com/gurps/books/conspiracyx/)

Various Alphabet Soups and their agents are fighting against alien and supernatural menaces, unified into Aegis. A lot of focus on pulling strings and operating at the organisation level.

## [Black Ops](http://www.sjgames.com/gurps/books/blackops/)

Sign up into the Company - an élite supersecret organisation consisting of the best of the best. Off the books, with a great budget and the fanciest of toys. Become the world's most hypercompetent commandos, technicians and so on. Fight aliens, gargoyles, warlock cabals and more.

## [Cabal](http://www.sjgames.com/gurps/books/cabal/)

A game of magical conspiracy. Various supernatural creatures participating in a mutual-assistance society hiding from the muggles.

---

Keep in mind that most of the books are aimed at Third Edition (except the new ***Madness Dossier***), which is commonly considered to be less elegant and less balanced in certain areas (notably psionics); some conversion may be required.

Comment: Wouldn't you know if there isn't any X-Files series related?

Comment: @Vasconcelos1914 That would require a license. We're not cleared for that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the collected [*Suppressed*](https://www.sjgames.com/suppressed/) [*Transmission*](https://www.sjgames.com/suppressed2/) by Kenneth Hite. There are two published volumes available from SJG, and some from the weekly incarnation of
*Pyramid* that weren't collected, if you have access to those archives. Lots of random bits of weirdness to inspire you!